# Linux Compile simple program to run on both x86 and x64

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

How can I compile it on a 32-bit system so it can run as backward compatible under a 64-bit system? I know it can be done because Adobe, Dropbox and other companies have such binaries. How should I link them, dynamically, statically? Static only some libraries and other dynamic?

I'm talking about a simple code like:

```
int main() {
  printf("Hello world!\n");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's called cross compiling. It's a bit of a mess unless you use a tool such as configure or cmake. Also you need to install gcc for cross compilation.

Comment: @Alexis I wouldn't call adding `-m32` to a command a mess, nor would I call it cross compilation, although you might say that in a strict sense.

Comment: If you look at the configure scripts, they call even the -m32 on a 64bit (and vice versa) a cross compilation setup... Now I agree that since you can run 32 bit software on your 64 bit platform without special interpreters, it sounds a bit silly. The other way around though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you compile either both versions, or compile only a 32-bit version, and require that the user has the 32-bit libraries installed.

You can tell GCC to compile for 32-bit by adding `-m32` to every command. Note that this requires a multilib compiler, and you need to have the necessary lib32* files installed.

Comment: So if I get this `./hello: No such file or directory` on an 64-bit system with a 32-bit compiled program is because I lack the 32-bit libraries.

Comment: @xtmtrx no that might be because your executable is either absent or not, well, executable. Verify the output is called `hello`, and then do a `chmod +x hello`, although the compiler should do this automatically. Also, do an `ldd hello` and see if all libraries can be found.

Comment: Is executable. `not a dynamic executable` (was compiled with a static library but left libc as dynamic). `hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xdd94b04d4b8bca92e94f3e1ce13a97c180b30493, stripped`; `-rwxrw-rw- 1 xtmtrx xtmtrx 22068 Feb 11 12:31 hello`

Comment: Then I have no idea. It seems your shell is very uninformative ;-). You might be missing the 32-bit GCC runtime libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Normally. Then install the 32-bit libraries on the 64-bit system.